# Check if browser has been closed

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am automating a webpage that has an 'Exit Application' button. Upon clicking this button the browser is closed.

How can I verify that once clicking this button that the browser is closed?

Comment: Check it by the running processes in the task manager?

Answer (score 1):

Hope below code works for your case.

```
try {
    driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("Browser Window is still exist");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Brower window is closed");
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. This does work. However, what I failed to mention in my original post was I don't want it to print anything in the console unless there is a failure, i.e the browser is still open.

Comment: public Boolean verifyWindowClose(){
try {
    driver.getTitle();
    return false;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
    return true;
      }}
Boolean browserClose= verifyWindowClose();
if(browserClose==false){
System.out.println("Browser window is not closed");
}

Comment: Is it works for you? If yes, please accept the answer so that it might useful for others

Comment: Sorry, does not work for me. I am using cucumber if that helps. The code you gave 1st works fine. I just need to have it where it is only printing something in the console when it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium has no readymade method to check if browser is open or close, but there is a workaround to this. You can try doing this:

```
/*
* returns true if browser is open, else retrurns false
*/
public boolean isBrowserOpen() {
    try {
        driver.getTitle(); //can also use driver.getCurrentUrl()
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then in your method, add this line

```
if(!isBrowserOpen())
    System.out.println("Browser was still open");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("tasklist");
Process process = builder.start();
String string = toString(process.getInputStream());
// find ie process name by regexp
```